# n="+".join(n) TypeError: can only join an iterable

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have been trying a face recognition attendance program using Python with following module but having an issue. I tried commenting the `n="+".join(n)` but it does not shows the details on the cv capture window instead it just shows None in the Course, Semester, Roll No, and Name fields.

```
def mark_attendance(self,i,r,n,name):
    with open("attendance.csv","r+",newline="\n") as f:
        myDatalist=f.readlines()
        name_list=[]
        for line in myDatalist:
            entry=line.split((","))
            name_list.append(entry[0])

        if((name not in name_list) and (i not in name_list)):
            now=datetime.now()
            d1=now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
            dtString=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            f.writelines(f"{n}, {r}, {i}, {name}, {dtString}, {d1}, Present\n")

#================face recognition==================
def face_recog(self):
    def draw_boundray(img,classifier,scaleFactor,minNeighbors,color,text,clf):
        gray_image=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        features=classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image,scaleFactor,minNeighbors)

        coord=[]
        
        for (x,y,w,h) in features:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
            id,predict=clf.predict(gray_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])

            confidence=int((100*(1-predict/300)))

            conn = mysql.connector.connect(username='root', password='',host='localhost',database='face_recognition',port=3306)
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.execute("select Course from student where Roll_No="+str(id))
            n=cursor.fetchone()
            n="+".join(n)

            cursor.execute("select Semester from student where Roll_No="+str(id))
            r=cursor.fetchone()
            r="+".join(r)

            cursor.execute("select Roll_No from student where Roll_No="+str(id))
            i=cursor.fetchone()
            i="+".join(i)

            cursor.execute("select Name from student where Roll_No="+str(id))
            name=cursor.fetchone()
            name="+".join(name)


            if confidence > 77:
                cv2.putText(img,f"Course: {n}",(x,y-105),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(64,15,223),2)
                cv2.putText(img,f"Semester: {r}",(x,y-80),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(64,15,223),2)
                cv2.putText(img,f"Roll No: {i}",(x,y-55),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(64,15,223),2)
                cv2.putText(img,f"Name: {name}",(x,y-30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(64,15,223),2)
                self.mark_attendance(i,r,n,name)
            else:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
                cv2.putText(img,"Not Found",(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,0),3)   

            coord=[x,y,w,y]
        
        return coord    


    #==========
    def recognize(img,clf,faceCascade):
        coord=draw_boundray(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,25,255),"Face",clf)
        return img
    
    faceCascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    clf.read("clf.xml")

    videoCap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret,img=videoCap.read()
        img=recognize(img,clf,faceCascade)
        cv2.imshow("Face Detector",img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    videoCap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The terminal shows following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khursaid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Final Project\New FAS\login.py", line 417, in face_recog
    img=recognize(img,clf,faceCascade)
  File "E:\Final Project\New FAS\login.py", line 406, in recognize
    coord=draw_boundray(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,25,255),"Face",clf)
  File "E:\Final Project\New FAS\login.py", line 374, in draw_boundray
    n="+".join(n)
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

What should I do?

Comment: what's the value of `type(n)`? and why would that be? you must review [mre]

Comment: Your `cursor.fetchone()` call returns a single value. Is it an iterable value? What you can do is collect the `Course`, `Semester`, `Roll_no` and `Name` into an iterable like an array or tuple then use the `"+".join(iterable)`. Alternatively, ditch the join method and just concatenate the values you want.

Comment: By changing the coord[x,y,w,h] the above code worked well for once and again after restarting the program it is again the TypeError: can only join an iterable.